# How to Rollout new log file based on programmatic trigger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to rollout new log files when I decide programmatically.

My application has call's to remote service it send bunch of messages every time I call them.

I want to log this messages into log file such as `msg.0.log`, and `msg.1.log` subsequently every time I do a remote call.

My application do has rolling based on `file size` but how can I implement rolling based on custom notifications.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RolllingLogs.class.getName());

try {
    //
    // Creating an instance of FileHandler with 5 logging files
    // sequences.
    //
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("myapp.log", 1024, 5, true);
    handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(handler);
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    logger.info("Logging information message.");
    logger.warning("Logging warning message.");

} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.warning("Failed to initialize logger handler.");
}
```

Comment: log4j is not the same as log4j2, which one are you actually using?

Comment: @D.B. I removed log4j2 tag. I am only using log4j

Comment: Thanks for updating, is there any chance you could upgrade to log4j2 or are you required to use log4j?

Comment: @D.B. Project only has log4j dependency. I won't be able to do that now (for env upgrade in-future we can think about it)

Comment: @D.B. As of right now my question is can we implement new File Handler which can support such activities ?

Comment: Looking closer at your code I don't think you're using log4j, this looks like java.util.logging - can you share your imports?

Comment: @D.B. yes it is. For log4J we have `rollingfileappender` both of this approach only roll overs file based on `TIME` and `SIZE`

Comment: You will probably need to implement either your own log4j `Appender` or your own `FileHandler` if you use java.util.logging.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented custom appender,

Let me explain every log message goes through the `publish` method which is present inside the `FileHandler`.

So in theory if we implement trigger which can pragmatically be flipped then we can switch file when we want.

Do following simple step and it will work,

1. Create custom class name whatever you want.
2. Copy code from `FileHandler` and put into our class.
3. Made following changes to `Publish` method.

Code,

```
@Override
public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
    if (!isLoggable(record)) {
        return;
    }
    super.publish(record);
    flush();
    // `changeFile` variable is declared by me
    // whenever i set true for this variable
    // new log file will be created 
    if (limit > 0 && changeFile) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {
                rotate();
                return null;
            }
        });
        // once log file is created turn the flag back to false.
        changeFile = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [observer](https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java) design pattern. After every remote call send internal notification and change your log.output file name when processing it.